# Does method injection with Guice work if constructor is not injected?

Tags: java, guice

I have a class where I need to inject a variable but the constructor is not guice injected.

```
public class Foo{
  private boolean x;
  public Foo(){
     //sets some variables
  }

  @Inject
  public void setX(boolean x){
     this.x=x;
  }
}
```

The value of x is not getting injected. Is it necessary to use injection in constructor for guice to recognize method injection?
Do I need to call this method from some other class for this to work?
Thanx in advance

Comment: show us the dependencies you set?

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to use Guice to `@Inject` `Foo` then Guice needs to create the object - either from the injector or from another `@Inject` point in separate class. Guice can't help you inject objects that it didn't create.

In this case it's not necessary to add `@Inject` to the constructor because Guice can automatically inject a no argument constructor. For example:

```java
public class MethodInjectionTest {

  static class Foo {
    private boolean x;
    public Foo(){
      //sets some variables
    }

    @Inject
    public void setX(boolean x){
      this.x=x;
    }
  }

  Injector i = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
    protected void configure() {
      bind(Boolean.class).toInstance(Boolean.TRUE);
    }
  });

  @Test
  public void methodInjection() {
    Foo foo = i.getInstance(Foo.class);
    assertThat(foo.x, is(true));
  }

  // EDIT: An example based on the comment by @JeffBowman
  @Test
  public void memberInjection() {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    i.injectMembers(foo);
    assertThat(foo.x, is(true));
  }

}
```

If your real world class has a need to mix Guice controlled dependencies with client provided dependencies during construction have a look at [assisted inject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject)

Comment: Guice _can_ help you inject objects it didn't create, though it takes an extra step ([Injector.injectMembers(Object)](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/Injector.html)) and introduces a weird inconsistently-injected API. Do so only in the weirdest legacy cases, and prefer fully-injected instances as described above.

Comment: @condit what if the constructor does have arguments and is not Guice injected? will the method injection work then?

Comment: Only if you use `injectMembers` as @JeffBowman mentioned. But then you need access to the `Injector` and it's really meant for legacy cases. I've updated the code in the answer with an example.